# Optimize slow COUNT in MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery, count

I have the following query that takes minutes to complete:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Designation, Model, (
    SELECT COUNT( Equipment.EquipmentID ) 
    FROM Equipment 
    INNER JOIN EquipmentDesignation_Vw ON Equipment.EquipmentID = EquipmentDesignation_Vw.EquipmentID 
    LEFT JOIN EquipmentIssuance_Vw eqpi on Equipment.EquipmentSerial = eqpi.EquipmentSerial 
    WHERE Equipment.ItemID = i.ItemID 
    AND EquipmentDesignation_Vw.Designation = ed.Designation 
        AND EquipmentDesignation_Vw.ArmoryID IN 2 
    AND ((eqpi.IssueLocationID is NULL) OR (eqpi.IssueLocationID is not NULL AND eqpi.ReturnLocationID is not NULL ))
) AS Total
FROM Item i 
INNER JOIN ItemSubCategory isc ON i.ItemSubCategoryID = isc.ItemSubCategoryID
LEFT JOIN Equipment e ON e.ItemID = i.ItemID
LEFT JOIN EquipmentDesignation_Vw ed ON e.EquipmentID = ed.EquipmentID
LEFT JOIN EquipmentIssuance_Vw ei on ei.EquipmentSerial = e.EquipmentSerial
WHERE ed.Designation = 'Issue'
    AND ed.ArmoryID IN 2   
    AND i.ItemCategoryID = 7
```

This is because of the nested SELECT COUNT subquery. Without it, it runs blazing fast.

I made sure to add indexes on all the columns used to perform the JOINS.

If I extract the COUNT subquery to its own query, it is also really fast:

```
SELECT i.ItemID, COUNT( Equipment.EquipmentID ) 
FROM Equipment 
INNER JOIN Item i on i.ItemID = Equipment.ItemID 
INNER JOIN EquipmentDesignation_Vw ON Equipment.EquipmentID = EquipmentDesignation_Vw.EquipmentID 
LEFT JOIN EquipmentIssuance_Vw eqpi on Equipment.EquipmentSerial = eqpi.EquipmentSerial 
WHERE Equipment.ItemID = i.ItemID AND EquipmentDesignation_Vw.Designation = 'Issue' 
AND EquipmentDesignation_Vw.ArmoryID IN 2 
AND ((eqpi.IssueLocationID is NULL) OR (eqpi.IssueLocationID is not NULL AND eqpi.ReturnLocationID is not NULL )) 
GROUP BY i.ItemID
```

I tried to remove the subquery and calling COUNT directly in the SELECT, but to get the same results as the original query, I need to add the `AND ((eqpi.IssueLocationID is NULL) OR (eqpi.IssueLocationID is not NULL AND eqpi.ReturnLocationID is not NULL ))` condition to the main query. By doing so, I am not sure that I will not affect the original results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Designation, Model, COUNT( e.EquipmentID ) 
FROM Item i 
INNER JOIN ItemSubCategory isc ON i.ItemSubCategoryID = isc.ItemSubCategoryID
LEFT JOIN Equipment e ON e.ItemID = i.ItemID
LEFT JOIN EquipmentDesignation_Vw ed ON e.EquipmentID = ed.EquipmentID
LEFT JOIN EquipmentIssuance_Vw ei on ei.EquipmentSerial = e.EquipmentSerial
WHERE ed.Designation =  'Issue'
AND ed.ArmoryID  IN 2   
AND ((ei.IssueLocationID is NULL) OR (ei.IssueLocationID is not NULL AND ei.ReturnLocationID is not NULL ))
GROUP BY i.ItemID
```

This is quite fast as well, and seems to return the same results as the original query but I am not certain about this.

So is there a way to get rid of this subquery, or at least to make it more performant?

This is the output of EXPLAIN EXTENDED for the original query
[image: output of EXPLAIN EXTENDED for the original query]

Thank you. I am not a DBA, I spent hours on this and feel a bit stuck here.

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` references `_fi2`, but that is not in any of the queries -- Please fix.  Also, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: RickJames this is because it is contained in one of the _Vw tables that are actually views: https://pastebin.com/VQekr5xL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Akine I did this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Designation, Model,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ((ei.IssueLocationID IS NULL) OR (ei.IssueLocationID IS NOT NULL AND ei.ReturnLocationID IS NOT NULL )) THEN e.EquipmentID ELSE NULL END) AS Total
FROM Item i
INNER JOIN ItemSubCategory isc ON i.ItemSubCategoryID = isc.ItemSubCategoryID
INNER JOIN Equipment e ON e.ItemID = i.ItemID
INNER JOIN EquipmentDesignation_Vw ed ON e.EquipmentID = ed.EquipmentID
LEFT JOIN EquipmentIssuance_Vw ei on ei.EquipmentSerial = e.EquipmentSerial
WHERE ed.Designation = 'Issue'
AND ed.ArmoryID  IN 2 
GROUP BY i.ItemID
```